# save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tran'

Tags: python, django

My save() method is throwing the error: `save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tran'`.
I overrode the save() method in the model “Transactions” as follows:

```
def save(self,D,tran):
        self.DATE=D
        self.TYPE=tran.SERVICE_CODE
        self.SUCCESS=tran['Success']
        self.TECHNICAL_DECLINES=tran['Technical_declines']
        self.BUSINESS_DECLINES=tran['Business_declines']
        self.TOTAL=self.SUCCESS+self.TECHNICAL_DECLINES+self.BUSINESS_DECLINES
        self.PERCENTAGE_TECH_DEC=((T/(self.TOTAL))*100)
        super(Transactions,self).save()
```

where `tran` argument in the save() is a dictionary object passed on from views. Please note that I have also tried `super(Transactions,self).save(D,tran)` in the last line of `save()`.

views.py

```
def fetch():
    DATE=datetime.datetime.now()
    print(DATE)
    status=Transactions.objects
    obj=wf()
    for tran in obj:
        print(tran)
        Transactions.save(DATE,tran)
    return Transactions.objects.all()
```

Here wf() is a function retrieve database object from a model. From the output of `print(tran)` it is clear that the db_object is being fetched without any issue.

output of print():

```
{'SERVICE_CODE': 'APY', 'Success': 1, 'Technical_declines': 0, 'Business_declines': 0}
```

I don't understand where the argument `tran` is being missed.

Comment: You're calling it as a class method. You need to call `save` on an *instance*. Otherwise `self` becomes the first argument, `D` the second argument, and you're missing the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @deceze you are calling the save() method on the Transactions class, not on the transaction instance you wish to save. You need to call save on the instance

```
def fetch():
    DATE=datetime.datetime.now()
    print(DATE)
    status=Transactions.objects
    obj=wf()
    for tran in obj:
        print(tran)
        tran.save(DATE,tran)
    return Transactions.objects.all()
```

Also in your save method you are using dot notation to access an entry in a dict, this will not work.

```
self.TYPE=tran.SERVICE_CODE
self.TYPE=tran["SERVICE_CODE"]
```

Comment: what if `wf()` queries data from a different model other than `Transactions`, and of a different Database(DB2) than Transactions, which belongs to the Database(DB1)?

Comment: wf() should be able to access other models like any other function. Im not sure what you mean by a second database, to my knowledge Django does not support multiple databases running rogether.